# How to erase my user data on company's macbook?

Tags: macos

My company gave to me macbook. I want to give it back to company so I want to erase data form my user. Is there any solution? os macos big sur 11.2.3

Comment: Ave you an Admin account on this Mac?

Comment: Delete the user may be sufficient. Then use disk utility to write zeroes?

Comment: Questions about this have come up before, I've linked to one of them at the top of your question.